# How many lags to use in ADF test?

Tags: time-series, model-selection, autoregressive, lags, augmented-dickey-fuller

So I've ran a ADF test on my data multiple times with different lags and all up to a lag of 4 have a p-value below .05. So in this case how many lags do you decide to use? Could this also provide a clue as to how many lags to use if fitting an autoregressive model?